# Query in Elasticsearch for retrieving strings that start with a particular word

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write a query in elasticsearch such that it will only give results where string starts from a particular word for example i have one string "Donald Duck" and the other string which is "Alan Donald" now if i will search for "Donald" with below query

```
"query": {
     query_string: {
         query: "Donald",
         fields: ['character_name']
     }
 }
```

then result should be "Donald Duck" not "Alan Donald" because in "Donald Duck" it starts with "Donald". Now can anyone please tell me how can i write such a query, i have searched a lot of posts but haven't found any solution.

Edit-1

My mapping is given below

```
"settings": {
        "index": {
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "simple_wildcard": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      },
      "mappings" : {
        "college": {
                "properties":{
                    "character_name" : { "type" : "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "simple_wildcard"}

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the match phrase prefix? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Comment: Would searching for "Donald " (space at the end) work?

Comment: It might be worth considering how you are structuring your data. You should structure data in Elastic Search based on how you want to search, in this case you could split first name and last name into separate fields and search just the 'first_name' field.

Comment: for "Donald " result must be Donald Duck as "Donald Duck" starts with "Donald".

Comment: @NickG No for match phrase prefix it will return both if i will search for "DONALD" but thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Limit Token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-limit-token-count-tokenfilter.html) would be very helpful in this particular case. You can analyze *character_name* field in two different ways, one for standard search operations and other to get the string starting with particular word. I created the sample index like this. **only_first** indexes only the first token of the string.

```
PUT character
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "character_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "one_token_limit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "one_token_limit": {
          "type": "limit",
          "max_token_count": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "character_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "only_first": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "character_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you query on the *only_first* field like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["character_name.only_first"],
      "query": "Donald"
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the desired results. I have used [whitespace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) tokenizer but you can also go for standard tokenizer if you want to match "donald-donald duck".

Another way is [span first query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-first-query.html) but the problem is it is a `term query` so 'donald' will match but 'Donald' wont match

```
{
    "span_first" : {
        "match" : {
            "span_term" : { "character_name" : "donald" }
        },
        "end" : 1
    }
}
```

But 'Donald' will give you zero results(**case sensitive**), but the first approach will definitely work.

**EDIT 1** : Prefix Match

You can wrap prefix query inside span first like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "span_first": {
      "match": {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "prefix": {
              "character_name": {
                "value": "don"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "end": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Do not** use **"*"** in query.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot man span_first query is working fine for me, there is just one thing left how to combine span_first query with a wildcard query inside it instead of a match query because i want to search for "Donal*" also and for this my es should return "Donald Duck".

Comment: I have edited my answer. I am not sure why you are not using 'limit token' approach as span queries are case sensitive. You would have to 100% sure that it wont cause any problem in future. What is the mapping of character_name field?

Comment: you can check my edited post i have updated my mapping, also as i am lowercasing all my tokens so i don't think case sensitive will be a problem.

Comment: thanks a lot man prefix match query worked like a charm, thanks for helping me out of here.

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing how can i fix position for a word for e.g i want "Donald" to appear exactly on 3rd position what should be my query then.

Comment: i mean now i want to check whether first word appears at first position and second appears at second position and so on.

Comment: This is kind of very precise search. I think you need start thinking about various queries you will be performing and accordingly store the data(analyzers and filters). I can only think of boolean clauses right now where you search for individual word with end position incremented. Please try asking separate question. You might get some better answers.

Comment: hey i solved that by using bool query and breaking down my query into words. One last question can you please help me at this question please please help me it will be really appreciable  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138638/in-span-first-query-can-we-specify-end-paramter-based-on-actual-string-that-is

Comment: are you there can you please help me out.

Comment: I have commented on the specific question, I will look more into it during weekend.