# In span_first query can we specify "end" paramter based on actual string that is stored in ES or do i have to specify in terms of tokens stored in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I asked previous question here [Query in Elasticsearch for retrieving strings that start with a particular word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109674/query-in-elasticsearch-for-retrieving-strings-that-start-with-a-particular-word/40111018?noredirect=1#comment67531986_40111018) on elasticsearch and my problem was solved by using span_first query but now my problem has been changed a bit, now my mapping has been changed because now i want to store words ending with apostrophe 's' as "word", "words", "word's" for example see below case

```
      "joseph's -> "joseph's", "josephs", "joseph"
```

My mapping is given below

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/colleges/" -d 
'{
   "settings": {
        "index": {
                "analysis": {
                "char_filter": {
                    "apostrophe_comma": {
                        "type": "pattern_replace",
                        "pattern": "\\b((\\w+)\\u0027S)\\b",
                        "replacement": "$1 $2s $2"
                    }
                },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "simple_wildcard": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "char_filter" : ["apostrophe_comma"],
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "unique"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      },
      "mappings" : {
        "college": {
                "properties":{
                    "college_name" : { "type" : "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "simple_wildcard"}
                }
            }
     }
   }'
```

My span_first query i was using

```
"span_first" : {
        "match" : {
             "span_term" : { "college_name" : first_string[0] }
        },
        "end" : 1
 }
```

Now the problem i am facing is consider below example

Suppose i have "Donald Duck's" now if anyone would search for "Donald Duck", "Donald Duck's", "Donald Ducks" etc i want them to give "Donald Duck's" but by using span_first query it is not happening because as due to mapping i have 4 tokens now "Donald", "Duck", "Ducks" and "Duck's". now for Donald "end" used in span_first query will be 1, but for other three i used 2 but as "end" is different for different tokens of same word i am not getting desired result.

In short my problem is as span_first query uses "end" parameter to describe position from beginning my token must be present now as due to my mapping i have broken one word "Duck's" to "Duck's", "Ducks" and "Duck" because of which all have "end" value different but while querying i can only use one "end" parameter that's why i don't know how to get my desired output.

If anyone of you have worked on span_first query please help me.

Comment: I looked at the problem. `'s` problem can be solved by [english possesive stemmer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/choosing-a-stemmer.html) which removes `'s` and then you would also have to remove it while querying. As far as plurals are concerned, you could just remove trailing `s` from all the words but then It might give some unwanted results.

Comment: "As far as plurals are concerned, you could just remove trailing s from all the words but then It might give some unwanted results" Yes but that is all the problem i am facing thanks a lot man for helping me out of here.

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I am eagerly waiting for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use english possessive stemmer to remove **'s** and english stemmer which maps to [porter stem algorithm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-porterstem-tokenfilter.html) to handle plurals.

```
POST colleges
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "simple_wildcard": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "unique",
              "english_possessive_stemmer",
              "light_english_stemmer"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "light_english_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "english"
          },
          "english_possessive_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "possessive_english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "college": {
      "properties": {
        "college_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "simple_wildcard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that you will have to make two queries to get the right result. First you would have to run the user query through [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to get the tokens which you will pass to span queries.

```
GET colleges/_analyze
{
  "text" : "donald ducks duck's",
  "analyzer" : "simple_wildcard"
}
```

The output would be the tokens which will be passed to next phase i.e span query.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "donald",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "duck",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "duck",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The tokens *donald*, *duck*, *duck* will be passed with **end** position as 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

**NOTE** : No stemming algorithm is 100%, you might miss some singular/plural combination. For this you could log your queries and then use either [synonym](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) token filter or [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) char filter.

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: I dont think it will work as if i would store "saint mary's convent college" then i am getting "mari" in tokens.

Comment: Yes, you are right but as I said this is not 100%, you could use synonym `'mari => mary'` and then it will work.